Is there a way to measure "dns lookups", I'm getting an error for my SPF record
Basically I have two includes in my SPF record one is bluehost's welcomewebsite.com and the other is google's.  We send both from our bluehost webmail and from gmail (via send as through bluehost's SMTP server).
With both of those I get "Too many included lookups (16)".
I tried resolving the bluehost one and putting the IP address in, but then it gets flagged for "improper syntax" and "Misconfigured... can't be parsed" depending on which tool I'm using to check it.
I know it won't help me to know this, but at least if I knew the bluehost lookups were like 8 or something I could complain about it better.  Not that they will likely help.

Why not tell us the domain name so that we can actually help?

I'm assuming you mean websitewelcome.com

I literally said it in the first line of my post.  My personal domain is irrelevant since it's not hopping from there.  Bluehost says to use that domain and google says go use _spf.google.com.
Those are the dns lookups that are happening regardless of the domain that is using the SPF record.

Every "MX" is one lookup plus another lookup for each MX record returned; and every "A" is one lookup; "IP4", "IP6", and "all" are zero lookups; and "include" is one lookup in addition to the lookups for  whatever it points to.
Kitterman is my preferred tool.
https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html
(python source is available)
spf.websitewelcome.com descriptive text "v=spf1 ip4:192.185.0.0/16 
 ip4:50.116.64.0/18  ip4:50.87.152.0/21 ip4:108.167.128.0/18
 ip4:216.172.160.0/19 ip4:108.179.192.0/18 ip4:162.144.0.0/16 -all"

one lookup for the include
_spf.google.com descriptive text "v=spf1 
include:_netblocks.google.com
include:_netblocks2.google.com
include:_netblocks3.google.com
~all"

That's google wasting 3 lookups out of evilness, laziness, or stupidity.
There is no length limit on SPF records - they can be continued by returning a multi-part result, if their include contains further includes. they're being silly, consider changing to a provider who can demonstrate good will and basic literacy.
So far 5 lookups, 6 counting your undisclosed SPF record itself.
If you also say MX and A you could easily be over the limit.
TLDR if you're using a mailbox provider that has several MX records, use their include and don't use MX in your SPF record.

So, it's actually not google... not directly, Bluehost uses Google, makes me wonder if I even need to ~include google at if that is happening?
This is what it looks like:
Have to put it in the next post.
I short handed it,
x10 means that under that FQD was 10 cidr IP's and so on.

a
x1
mx
x1
include:websitewelcome.com
x2
include:eig.spf.a.cloudfilter.net
x2
~all
include:spf.websitewelcome.com
x7
-all
include:spf1.websitewelcome.com
x10
include:spfgwp.websitewelcome.com
x7
include:_spf.google.com
include:_netblocks.google.com
x11
~all
include:_netblocks2.google.com
x6
~all
include:_netblocks3.google.com
x10
~all
~all
include:spf.protection.outlook.com
x9
-all
-all
include:_spf.google.com
include:_netblocks.google.com
x11
~all
include:_netblocks2.google.com
x5
~all
include:_netblocks3.google.com
x10
~all
~all
~all

Gross, that didn't work worth a F.
Here is a copy formatted and full, but only will be up a day.
https://ctxt.io/2/AAAYH145EQ

oh if you're doing  include:websitewelcome.com  that's 10 lookups itself.  game over.
